# How can I access the method of a child component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a child component, which is built into the parent. I want to access the child's method from the parent. I want to use `$refs` for this purpose.

**Template:**

```html
<template>
  <div>Parent!</div>
</template>
```

**Script:**

```html
<script>
    Vue.component('child',{
      template: `<div>I am child</div>`,
    }
    export default {
       name: 'Parent'
    }
</script>
```

How could I declare `$refs` for my child in this case?

Comment: you could show the child method and how do you want to use it in parent component?

Answer (score 3):

To achieve that, you can assign a reference ID to the child component using the `ref` attribute.

```
<template>
  <div>Parent!</div>
  <child ref="childComponent"/>
</template>
```

Now you can get access to your child component instance from your parent component by using it as such:

```
this.$refs.childComponent // where componentName is the ref value
```

That also means you can execute the methods that you defined under your child component.

```
this.$refs.childComponent.myFunction();
```

See [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Accessing-Child-Component-Instances-amp-Child-Elements) for more details.

Comment: Also, a classic issue to stumble upon when new to Vue is that refs are only available in [mounted hook](https://vuejs.org/images/lifecycle.png) and after. (They are undefined otherwise) Also, if the ref is inside a v-if, you might need to wait for it in the updated hook.

Comment: Yup, that I was find out when I was trying to access a property of the child instance in the `created()` hook and it leads to that error.